# How can I add a new tab to JTabbedPane when a list item is selected in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am working on a project for "Human Resources Management".
In my project, I have basically divided the main screen horizontally using `JSplitPane`.
The second part of `JSplitPane` is further divided vertically where one side consists of `JList` and other side is `JTabbedPane`.
I want to add event listener to the list such that whenever a list item is selected from the left hand side of `JSplitPane`, a new tab should be opened on the right hand side of `JSplitPane`. How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class MainPage extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {
    JSplitPane mainPane;
    JSplitPane subPane;
    JList listOfTasks;
    JTabbedPane paneForTasks;

    String options[] = { "Add a new employee", "Attendance", "Payroll" };

    public MainPage() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        setVisible(true);

        listOfTasks = new JList(options);
        listOfTasks.addListSelectionListener(this);
        paneForTasks = new JTabbedPane();
        subPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, listOfTasks, paneForTasks);
        mainPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, labelLogo, subPane);
        add(mainPane);
    }

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        paneForTasks.addTab("Add Employee");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainPage obj = new MainPage();
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You've pretty much done it already (?). Just change it to `paneForTasks.addTab("Add Employee", theComponentToAdd);` and maybe add this if-statement before: `if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())` < Then only a new tab will appear if the selection actually changed.

Comment: And make sure to revalidate the parent of the tabbed pane.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Thank u for ur response. Can u just explain me what does e.getValueIsAdjusting specify?  I searched about it on the internet, but didn't  understand.